# System crashes when a USB device is plugged in or a web browser is opened

Tags: crash, hostapd, reboot

I recently turned my pi into a standalone network following this guide: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md
But now when I open a web browser, or plug in a usb device it crashes and reboots and sometimes even gets stuck in a boot loop causing to to pull the plug and restart it. (USB crashes happen about 50% of the time something is plugged in). I really don't know where to start troubleshooting this problem. Where should I be looking? Any tips or things to look out for?

Comment: When you say you plug in a USB device, is it a USB WiFi 'dongle'? What version is your RPi? ver 3, 3B, 4, etc?

Comment: Which model of Pi? What PSU? Which OS?

Comment: My first guess is that you're underpowering it, but it's a sWAG, so we need the details like @CoderMike asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an undervoltage situation. Keep in mind that phone chargers aren't the best when used as a PSU. Get a better charger or buy the raspberry pi official PSU.

I used to have this problem as well.